# Alpha to layout make all it's children have alpha ?Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to give alpha to only the relative layout which contains the textview but it give alpha to it's children too now textview have alpha too without give it anything i want to remove alpha from it and just leave on relative layout

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/phaseLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/phaseImage"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/pic1" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phaseImage"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     android:alpha=".6"
                        android:background="@drawable/text_view_border"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/phaseName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </FrameLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well, children inherit from their parent. What did you expect? Now cycle through all the children and set their alpha individually.

Comment: I did man but not work , i need to let the textview have black background with alpha .6 i tried so much and nothing work :(

Comment: But why do you need to set the parent's alpha?

Comment: Setting a background with a certain level of transparency is enough. And the background is not passed to the children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a background for the RelativeLayout and set a transparent color for the drawable.
drawable eg:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using alpha attribute to your Layout will result to apply alpha to all the child layouts and views. The better way is to apply/add alpha to background of the given layout. It will result to apply alpha to that layout only.

Below is the mapping :

```
Hex Opacity Values

100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

So If your colour code is #FFFFFF then your colour code will be #99FFFFFF means white colour with 60% transparency.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Quite off-topic. The OP didn't ask how to set the alpha. But why the alpha is inherited from parent to children.